# How to create a vector of missing values of certain length in julia?

Tags: julia

In `R` I can create a vector length 5 with all `NA_real_` values:

```
x <- 1:5
length(x)
## [1] 5
rep(NA_real_, times = length(x))
## [1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

How can I do the same in `julia`? I can create a vector containing zeros, but I don't know how to put missing values in there:

```
v = Vector{Float64}(undef, 5)
## 5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, 5)` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Missings.jl package also provides `missings(Float64, 5)` as a shorthand.

Answer (score 10):

The missing value in Julia is called `missing`. It is a singleton of type [`Missing`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/missing/). You can create a vector of missing values like this:

```
v = Vector{Missing}(undef, 5)
# 5-element Array{Missing,1}:
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing
```

Or, more conveniently using [`fill`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.fill):

```
v = fill(missing, 5)
```

Be warned, though, that unlike in R, `Missing` does not share a type with other numeric types: it is its own type. Notice what happens when you try to put a `Float64` into a vector of `Missing`s:

```
v = fill(missing, 5)
# 5-element Array{Missing,1}:
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing

v[1] = 3.14
# ERROR: MethodError: convert(::Type{Union{}}, ::Float64) is ambiguous.
```

This means if you want to create a vector containing only missing values, but you want it to also be able to contain a numeric value like a `Float64`, you should be explicit:

```
v = convert(Array{Union{Float64,Missing}}, v)
# 5-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}:
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing
#  missing

v[1] = 3.14;
v
# 5-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}:
#  3.14
#   missing
#   missing
#   missing
#   missing
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to learn julia to speed up a for-loop which is slow in R (do not have any other option to do what I want to do without the loop). But I think learning might take more time than the loop in R.

Comment: Yes, but "learning" is like compilation,  it takes time only once.